# Real Analysis, Folland Proposition 1.7 elementary family

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Definition - An elementary family is a collection $\varepsilon$ of subsets of $X$ such that

i.) $\emptyset\in \varepsilon$

ii.) if $E,F\in \varepsilon$ then $E\cap F\in \varepsilon$

iii.) if $E\in \varepsilon$ then $E^c$ is a finite disjoint union of members of $\varepsilon$

> 1.7 Proposition - If $\varepsilon$ is an elementary family, the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of members of $\varepsilon$ is an algebra.

Attempted proof:

i.) If $A,B\in \varepsilon$, set $B^c = \bigcup_{1}^{n} C_j$ where $\{C_j\}_{1}^{n}\subseteq \varepsilon$. Then $$A\setminus B = A\cap B^c = A\cap \left(\bigcup_{1}^{n}C_j\right) = \bigcup_{1}^{n}C_j\cap A$$ which is a finite disjoint union of members of $\varepsilon$. Thus we have closure under complements.

ii.) Now we can write $A\cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup B$ and we can see that $A\cup B\in \mathcal{A}$ (If more details needs to be provided please let me know)

iii.) Suppose for a fixed $n$ we always have $\bigcup_{1}^{n} A_j\in \mathcal{A}$ whenever $\{A_j\}_{1}^{n}\subset \varepsilon$. Thus, $$\bigcup_{1}^{n+1}A_j = A_{n+1}\cup \bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j$$

I am not sure where to go from here.

Any suggestions on this is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if something is not clear in what I have written so far or if this can be more neatly presented.

Comment: Step iii.) is not necessary since it follows directly from ii.) via induction. In addition, you might want to show that the entire space belongs to $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Ok, but I am pretty sure we still need to show by induction that $\bigcup_{1}^{n+1}A_j\in \mathcal{A}$ what do you mean that I should show the entire space belongs to $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: For the induction step, here is a hint: $\bigcup_{1}^{n+1} A_j = \left( \bigcup_{1}^{n} A_j \right) \cup A_{n+1}$. By definition of an algebra, we need $X \in \mathcal{A}$. This is easy to show but you havn't done it in the above?

Comment: I just added that step. But I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Since $B = \bigcup_{i}^{n} A_j \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A_{n+1} \in \mathcal{A}$, what does step ii.) tell you?

Comment: oh right that since $B\in \mathcal{A}$ and $A_{n+1}\in \mathcal{A}$ thenby (ii) we have a finite union of disjoint memebers of $\varepsilon$ thus $\bigcup_{1}^{n+1}A_j \in\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: What you proved in ii.) is that the union of any two sets of $\mathcal{A}$ is still in $\mathcal{A}$. So $B \cup A_{n+1} \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Could you just provide an answer to avoid a long discussion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is in the right direction.  Here is it in a complete form.

> 1.7 Proposition - If $\varepsilon$ is an elementary family, the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of members of $\varepsilon$ is an algebra.

**Proof:**

We begin by proving two auxiliary results:

i.) $\varepsilon \subseteq  \mathcal{A}$

Note that if $A\in \varepsilon$, then consider $\{C_j\}_1^1$ such that $C_1=A$. Then $\{C_j\}_1^1$ is a disjoint family of sets in $\varepsilon$, so $A=\bigcup_{j=1}^1C_j\in \mathcal{A}$. So $\varepsilon \subseteq  \mathcal{A}$.

ii.) Now let us prove that  for any  $\{A_j\}_{1}^{n}\subset \varepsilon$, ($\{A_j\}_{1}^{n}$ don't need to be disjoint), we have
$\bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j \in \mathcal{A}$.

We will divide the proof in two steps:

ii.a.) First we prove that: if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B\in \varepsilon$, then $A\cup B\in \mathcal{A}$.

If $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B\in \varepsilon$, then we have $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^m D_k$ where $\{D_k\}_{1}^{m}$ is a  family of disjoint sets in $\varepsilon$ and  $B^c = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} C_j$ where $\{C_j\}_{1}^{n}\subseteq \varepsilon$ and $\{C_j\}_{1}^{n}$ is a disjoint family of sets. Then $$A\setminus B = A\cap B^c =\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^m D_i\right)\cap \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}C_j\right) = \bigcup_{k=1}^m\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}C_j\cap D_k$$ which is a finite disjoint union of members of $\varepsilon$. So $A\setminus B \in \mathcal{A}$.

Now we can write $A\cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup B$. Since $A\setminus B$ is finite disjoint unions of members of $\varepsilon$, $B\in \varepsilon$ and $(A\setminus B)\cap B =\emptyset$,  we can see that $A\cup B\in \mathcal{A}$.

ii.b.) It follows by induction that, for all $n\geqslant 2$, if $\{A_j\}_{1}^{n}\subset \varepsilon$, , then $\bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j \in \mathcal{A}$.

In fact, for $n=2$ the result is follows immediately from items i.) and ii.a.).

Assume $n>2$ and that we know by induction hypothesis that $\bigcup_{1}^{n-1}A_j \in \mathcal{A}$, then just apply item ii.a.) to $\bigcup_{1}^{n-1}A_j$ and $A_n$ and we get that $\bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j= \left(\bigcup_{1}^{n-1}A_j\right)\cup A_n\in \mathcal{A}$.

So $\mathcal{A}$ is the the collection of finite unions of members of $\varepsilon$.

**Now let us prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra.**

1. $\emptyset \in \varepsilon \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. So $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$.
2. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is the the collection of finite unions of members of $\varepsilon$, it is immediate that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite unions. (finite union of finite unions are still just a finite union).
3. If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then we have $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^m D_k$ where $\{D_k\}_{1}^{m}$ is a family of disjoint sets in $\varepsilon$, then we have, for each $k\in \{1,\dots,m\}$,
   $$D_k^c= \bigcup_{j=1}^{n_k}B_{k,j}$$ where $B_{k,j}\in \varepsilon$. So we have
   $$A^c=\bigcap_{k=1}^m D_k^c=\bigcap_{k=1}^m\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^{n_k}B_{k,j} \right)= \bigcup\{B_{1,j_1}\cap \cdots \cap B_{m,j_m} : 1\leqslant j_k \leqslant n_k, 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m \}$$
   So $A^c$ is a finite union of of members of $\varepsilon$. Thus $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$.

So we have proved that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra.

Comment: Was there anything wrong in part (i) and (ii) of my proof?

Comment: Also, when showing $A\cup B\in\mathcal{A}$ once we show $A\setminus B\in \mathcal{A}$ then we can write $$A\cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup B = \cup_{1}^{n}\cup_{1}^{m}C_i\cap D_j \cup B = \cup_{1}^{n}\cup_{1}^{m}\emptyset \cup B = B$$ does this imply since $B\in \varepsilon$ we have $A\cup B\in\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: When proving $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra. For number 2, isn't $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of finite disjoint unions? not just finite unions.

Comment: @Wolfi By definition  $\mathcal{A}$ is the  collection of finite disjoint unions of sets in $\varepsilon$. HOWEVER, before proving that  $ \mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, we proved that:  for any  $\{A_j\}_{1}^{n}\subset \varepsilon$, ($\{A_j\}_{1}^{n}$ don't need to be disjoint), we have $\bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j \in \mathcal{A}$.  It measn that we proved that  $\mathcal{A}$ is the  collection of finite unions  of sets in $\varepsilon$. I have edited the answer to better highlight this point.

Comment: I see that now thanks, also I am working on exercise 16 here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806842/saturation-of-a-measure-folland-problem-1-3-16

Comment: But @Ramiro how can you interchange the unions and intersections in the last part of the proof to show  closure under complementation?

Comment: @LegendKiller Those unions and intersections are **finite** unions and  **finite** intersections . It is enough to distributive property to interchange them.

Comment: How do you show if $A \in \epsilon$ and $A \in \epsilon$ and A\B$ \in \mathcal{A}$ then A\B$\cup B \in \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: I found this way too compact in Folland. This definitely needed an explanation, at least for me, so thank you. Also the last step, i.e. that $A\in\mathcal{A}$ implies $A^c\in\mathcal{A}$, is more easily seen if one first writes out all of the $m$ sets whose intersection we are taking and then considers that $\cap$ distributes over $\cup$; that is that $A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B)$.

Comment: There's a typo in your answer, I think. $\{D_k\}_1^n$ should be $\{D_k\}_1^m$. And right after that, instead of "for $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$" it should be "for $k\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$".

Comment: @SimonSMN Thanks for pointing the typo. I have fixed it.